# Python throwing an error despite the code working correctly

Tags: python, shutil

I have some code in Python as follows:

```
folderPath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Program\folder/' + folderName
if not os.path.exists(folderPath):
    shutil.copytree('C:\Program Files (x86)\Program\folder\anotherfolder', folderPath)
```

The variable folderName is from the user input, essentially my program allows the user to create a folder and then some contents from another folder get copied into the new folder. You can think of it as a file backup system of sorts.

The thing that's odd enough is this. It works perfectly, the folder gets created (as outlined in the shutil docs) and the contents of the other folder gets copied, BUT, an error is raised:

```
[error] script [ myScript ] stopped with error in line 52
[error] shutil.Error ( ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Program\\folder\\anotherfolder', 'C:\\Program 
Files (x86)\\Program\\folder\\test', "[Errno 5] Input/output error: 'C:\\\\Program Files 
(x86)\\\\Program\\\\folder\\\\test'"] )
```

In this case the folderName I input was 'test'. Line 52 is the shutil.copytree() call.

My script then stops running even though the files all got copied and it worked all well and good.

How do I ignore this (if possible) and carry on with the script? Or how do I fix this, if this may indeed be a problem with my code?

All help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide a complete traceback? Or at least show line 52 (which probably just is the shutil.copytree call)...

Comment: That's the complete error I got. Line 52 is the shutil.copytree call.

Comment: You have a forward slash in the path in the first line That cant be good.

Comment: @LennartRegebro Something about Python, the os module, or Windows is smart enough to handle that.

Comment: I'm not on a windows machine, but can you tell us the output of `import errno; print errno.errorcode[5]`

Comment: @LennartRegebro: Speaking of which, I've tried using \\ and /, same outcome. If I use a single backslash I get a syntax error.

Comment: @mgilson: I get 'EIO'.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254292/avoid-program-exit-on-i-o-error) has something similar to your issue..

Comment: @user3201185 -- Well, it was worth a try.  that's not particularly helpful, (it just means "I/O Error").

Comment: @user3201185 That's because single backslash is an escape code. You should probably use double backslashs all the way. Welcome to Windows.

Comment: @LaurIvan: I just tried that out, same error gets raised.

Comment: I tried your code (on Vista) and got error 123, complaining that the filename (with the forward slash) was incorrect. Possibly other versions of Python/Windows will instead give teh above error.

Comment: Careful with those backslashes. `\f` is form feed. `\a` is "make a noise".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with shutil in jython see http://bugs.jython.org/issue1872

However this should not be your problem?

You got a forward slash in your path (/) this can't be good. In order to make your program work do the following.

```
folderPath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Program\folder/' + folderName
if not os.path.exists(folderPath):
    try:
        shutil.copytree('C:\Program Files (x86)\Program\folder\anotherfolder', folderPath)
    except Exception, exc:
        print exc
```

This will catch the error which is raised. If it happens again you should be able to get more detailed information about the error.

You could also use:

```
folderPath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Program\folder/' + folderName
if not os.path.exists(folderPath):
    try:
        shutil.copytree('C:\Program Files (x86)\Program\folder\anotherfolder', folderPath)
    except Exception:
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exc()
```

Edit: Be aware of the fact that your problem still exists! The Exception/Error is caught within the except clause, so the program does not crash. See comments and Laur Ivan's answer. This error happens because you don't have the access rights to do something in the Program Files directory.

I hope this helps. Greetings Xeun

Comment: also see @mgilson 's comment and use the print of the error code.

Comment: thats why ou should show us the traceback, which should be printed to the commandline whith the example above. In jython it was a problem regarding the atime and mtime which was updated. See http://bugs.jython.org/msg7033. However you still don't use jython, do you?

Comment: IMHO this only gracefully catches the exception; the underlying problem is still there.

Comment: Thats why I wanted to get more detailed information. Of course the problem is still there

Answer (score 2):

Digging a bit more:

According to [microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), errno 5 corresponds to access denied.

`copytree` uses `copy2()` which copies the file and then changes its permissions, times.

IMHO you don't have the rights to change (or retrieve) file attributes, so you get the file with whatever attributes you have yourself (your user, group...).

HTH

Comment: +1 for this answer. Access denied on a windows machine in the Program Files directory... was overlooking this.

Comment: I'm sure the original poster knows this, but the Windows folders `C:\\Program Files` and `C:\\Program Files (x86)` have restricted access in all modern versions of Windows. They need to be running with elevated permissions otherwise weird things will happen.

Comment: @Duncan: true, but the fact that `copytree` tries to copy attributes too is not really obvious :).